# Using States to handle changing of Buttons color, not working React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two functions.

The first function has this loop to create an array of buttons:

```
import RectBox from '../components/rectangleBox'
const [buttonID, setButtonId] = useState("");
var tempRows = [];

tempRows = json.results.map(i => i.dates)
for (var i = 0; i < tempRows[0].length; i++) {
        uiArray.push(<RectBox data={tempRows[0][i]} index = {i} updateParentComponent= 
         {getDate} isSelected= {buttonID}/>)
    }
```

This is the callback function when a user tries to tap the button. I set the state accordingly to track which button was tapped:

```
function getDate(selectedDate)
{
    setButtonId(selectedDate);
}
```

Inside of my button component:

```
export default function RectangleBox({data, index, updateParentComponent, 
 isSelected}) {

const color = {
    color:'#00FFFF'
};

const tapped= (e) => {
    console.log(isSelected)
    updateParentComponent(data)
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("isSelected ", isSelected);

}, [isSelected]);


return (
    <div className= {isSelected == data ? "rectBox p-2 border-2 border rounded-lg mt- 
      2 mr-5 bg-base" : "rectBox p-2 border-2 border-dimmer rounded-lg mt-2 mr-5 bg-base"} >

        <div className="flex justify-center">
            <button name = {data} key={data} className="text-dim font-semibold text- 
            lg" style={color}  onClick={tapped} > {isSelected === data ? "selected" + 
           data : data}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

The problem is the isSelected is never getting the new state change. I send the selectedButtons name to the parent's component and store it in a state. I then have that state as a parameter in . Why isn't RectBox getting the new state change?

Comment: Because you've called your component `RectangleBox` not `RectBox`?

Comment: added the import statement

Comment: You can't use `useState` outside of a function component.

You normaly should get the following error message in your code `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. `

Comment: This is inside of a function component. I did not show the full code only the part where I’m using the state.

Comment: What is `tempRows`? Could you share the structure of it?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: could you show the  value of `tempRows[0][0]`?

Comment: tempRows[0][0] is 2021-12-31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I had a function that was doing a for loop making the UI and then passing that array to the div.

However, when the parent's state changed, it was not updating the UI made in that loop. So instead, I stored the raw data in a var called rows, which was accessible to all functions, and then did a map function call directly in the div. Now when the parents state changes, it re-renders, and the map function will be called again.

```
<div className="no-scrolling" id={idName}>
                <div className="flex card">
                    
                    {rows.map((x) => (
                        <RectBox data={x} updateParentComponent= 
                        {getDate} isSelected= {buttonID}/>
                    ))}
                    
                </div>
              </div>
```